# Load remote assets into React-native app WebView

Tags: react-native, webview

Can a `react-native` application fetch for remote html/js/css/img files, save to local and load in a `WebView`?

### Context:

Take as an example the following app structure:

```
├── App.js
├── /remote-assets
│   └── /foo
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── styles.js
│       └── logo.jpg
└── /local-assets
    ├── util.js
    └── background.jpg
```

The idea is that the `App.js` fetches assets into the directoy `remote-assets` and later loads the `index.html` into a `WebView`. That html will also reference files that are in the same local path, like:

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<img src="logo.jpg" />
```

And also assets that are local, for example:

```html
<script src="../../local-assets/util.js"></script>
<img src="../../local-assets/background.jpg" />
```